# Record video using OpenCV in android

Tags: android, video, opencv, camera, recording

Is is possible to record video using openCV in android platform? I have read that OpenCv not supporting video recording for android or we can capture open picture not video , is it true?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the answer is negative. As [this discussion](http://answers.opencv.org/question/19593/how-to-record-video-from-videocamera-in-android/) concludes, VideoWriter class is not functional on Android.